# "Get ChildItem : Cannot find path" showing path I did not supply

Tags: powershell, path, filesystems

I inherited a script that should simply move files from -source to -target. I am prompted for both, and after supplying the paths, it tells me that it cannot find the path while showing a path that I absolutely did not submit, but can't figure out how it's arriving there.

```
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $true,
        Position = 0,
        HelpMessage = "Root of the folders or share to archive"
    )]
    [String] $source,
 
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $true,
        Position = 1,
        HelpMessage = "Path of the folder or share of archive"
    )]
    [string] $target,
 
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $false,
        Position = 3
    )]
    [int] $days = 30
)
 
# Get all the files from the source path, that are not shortcuts (*.lnk) and older than the days set
Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse |  
        Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer -and ((get-date) - $_.lastwritetime).totaldays -gt $days -and $_.extension -ne ".lnk"} |
            ForEach-Object {

# For each file build the destination path 
                $dest = $_.fullname -replace ([regex]::escape($source)), $target
 
# Move the files into the destination
                Move-Item -Path $_.fullname -Destination $dest -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
}
```

The log says "Cannot find path '\\appserver\abc$\Automation\Daily\Archive\appserver\abc$\Storage' because it does not exist" - see how it starts repeating itself? \\appserver\abc$\Automation\Daily\Archive\ is the location of the script, whereas \\appserver\abc$\Storage\ is what I am entering as **-source**. So I have no idea why it is looking at the path to the script, then appending the source path concurrently.

EDIT: This is how I am calling the script (from a little-known finance application called APX):

```
SHELL PowerShell \\appserver\abc$\Automation\Daily\Archive\ArchiveFiles.ps1 -source \\appserver\abc$\Dataport\dpdata -target \\appserver\abc$\Dataport\archived -days 30
```

Comment: Add some logging inside your ```foreach-object``` and check the variables contain the values you expect - e.g. ```write-host "source = '$source'"; write-host "target = '$target'"; write-host "fulllname = '$($_.FullName)'"; write-host "dest = '$dest'"```, then work backwards. My guess would be your ```-replace``` is doing something unexpected...

Comment: Could you explain the comment "add some logging"? Very little experience with Powershell, not sure what the first step would be there. Thanks

Comment: @mklement0 post has been edited now

Comment: Thanks, but please [format the command properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and also state what application you're calling from. With the proper formatting, you can represent the command exactly as it is being submitted in your environment.

Comment: Honestly not sure which of those formatting options applies to my command, sorry literally my first post here. It is finance related software nobody has ever heard of called APX. That command is in an APX "script", I save it and click Run which then calls the PS script.

Comment: I've performed the formatting for you this time. Note that I've removed the leading `\ ` from the paths, because I assume you only put it there so that `\\ ` would in effect be displayed. Note the question implied by  Steve Taylor's answer: Is APX "eating" `\ ` characters, because it interprets them as escape characters? If it does, you need `\\\\ ` at the start of each UNC path, and `\\ ` for each path-internal `\ `

Comment: Thank you. And yeah you are correct, I only added the extra backslashes here so they would be displayed. The format is correct in APX, and in fact using identical scripts for a different client and it works as intended. So I'm extra lost why the same formatting and everything is not working in this instance. Only difference is the pathing.

Answer (score 2):

When your script starts, it is beginning in the directory that you are running it from, so it *already in* `\\appserver\abc$\Automation\Daily\Archive\` and if you do not supply a [UNC resource prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention) such as `\\` or `A:\` then it will look for ChildItems from that directory down. So when you're supplying the folder path, it's appending that to its current directory and unable to find the new path.

As this would only happen if you had omitted the `\\` at the beginning of your string, I would only expect your output if you had submitted `appserver\abc$\Storage\` as your source. If you are sure you did supply the `\\`, then look more closely at whatever line of script is passing the command *to* this script, to see if there's a reason it's stripping the `\\` off beforehand.